# cant build gradle project after trying to add facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried adding facebook to my gradle file like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    repositories { mavenCentral() }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 59
        versionName "4.6.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'


}
```

ALso in facebook directions it says:

> A note for Android developers If you are using ProGuard on the release
>   build of your app, you must add this snippet to your app's
>   proguard-project.txt config file:
>
> -keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
>   -keepattributes Signature These flags are used to preserve generics signatures and to preserve type information used for reflection. Both
>   flags are necessary for the SDK to function correctly in an Android
>   app.

So in my pro guard file (I may have done this in the wrong file..):

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /Users/Mike/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
```

So when I try and build my project it throws this error:

[image]

And when I click that and try and fix it I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply install the latest version of *Android SDK Build-tools* from SDK Manager which I believe that it is **22** now.

And then change this line in your build.gradle

```
buildToolsVersion "21.1.3"
```

to the correct version.

```
buildToolsVersion "22"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `build.gradle` file is specifying a build tools version of 21.1.3 which is not a valid version.

At this time (3/11/15), the latest build tools version is 22 so change this line

`buildToolsVersion "21.1.3"`

to

`buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"`

and it will work.